# Page not found (404) Djnago отправка формы

Tags: python, django, django-model, error404

Когда отправляю форму, чтобы добавить в базу данных вылетает ошибка. Если добавляю через админ панель то все норм.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

views:

```
 def create(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = GForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
form = GForm()
context = {
    'form': form,
}
return render(request, "auctions/create.html", context)
```

urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
  path("", views.index, name="index"),
  path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
  path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
  path("register", views.register, name="register"),
  path("product/<int:g_id>/", views.product, name="product"),
  path("create", views.create, name="create")
]
```

htlm:

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
 <form action="post">
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{ form.as_p }}
 <input type="submit" value="Добавить">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
```

в коде

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('index'))
```

Comment: Пробовал, не помогло

Answer (score -2):

Наше решение.
Нужно было добавить в html в тег `form enctype`

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: весьма сомнительное решение, когда  у Вас в качестве action всё еще не указан url из urlpaterns

Comment: В смысле? Где не указан?